# Redux DropdownMenu element going out of div

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

Sorry this may be badly described but will try to describe this as best as I can:

What I'm trying to do is put so the Redux dropdown menu dropdown element is an element in the menu (next to about/Signout as shown in the below screenshot).
For some reason the dropdown element is not coming up at all in the menu, but does work in the index file.

[image]

The code for the menu is below,

Dropdown.js

```js
import * as DropdownMenu from '@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu';

export default function dropdownUserProfileMenu (){
  return (
  <>
    <DropdownMenu.Root>
      <DropdownMenu.Trigger className='trigger'>Settings</DropdownMenu.Trigger>

      <DropdownMenu.Content>
        <DropdownMenu.Item>New Item</DropdownMenu.Item>
        <DropdownMenu.Item>New Item 2</DropdownMenu.Item>
        <DropdownMenu.Item>New Item 3</DropdownMenu.Item>
        <DropdownMenu.Item>New Item 4</DropdownMenu.Item>
      </DropdownMenu.Content>
    </DropdownMenu.Root>
  </>
  )
};
```

Menu.js

```js
 <div className='w-screen mr-3 h-16 drop-shadow-md rounded-sm bg-white'>
            <div className='container px-4 md:px-0 h-full mx-auto flex justify-between items-center shadow-md'>
                <div className='text-primaryBlack'>
                    <Link href='/'><p className='pl-4'>Student sharing site</p></Link>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul id='menuElements' className={`right-0 px-10 py-16 text-primaryBlack z-50 flex mx-auto flex-row space-x-4 items-center`}>
                        <Link href='/about'><li>About</li></Link>
                        <li><dropdownUserProfileMenu></dropdownUserProfileMenu></li>
                        <Link href='/api/auth/signout'><li onClick={e => {
                            e.preventDefault()
                            signOut()
                        }}>Signout</li>
                        </Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        // </div>
```

(Ignore the signin/signout methods, am using NextAuth specifically but this is not needed to get this working)
Hope helping for this is possible!